# Replacing Double Quotes of Specific Column Entries in CSV File?

Tags: python, csv

I have a huge CSV file with sample data that looks like so:

```
"Name";"Current balance";"Account";"Transfers";"Description";"Payee";"Category";"Date";"Memo";"Amount";"Currency";"Check #";"Tags"
"Capital One Quicksilver";"-119.99";"USD";"";"";"";"";";"";"";";"";""
"";"";"Capital One Quicksilver";"";"DMV";""Carfax";"";"08/19/2004";"";"-24.99";"USD";"";""
"";"";"Capital One Quicksilver";"";"DMV";""Carfax";"";"08/19/2004";"";"-24.99";"USD";"";""
"";"";"Capital One Quicksilver";"";"Gas";""USA Petroleum";"";"09/13/2004";"";"-20.43";"USD";"";""
```

The original CVS file had some unnecessary characters that I removed to obtain the data as shown above using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

text = open("report.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
      .replace('old', 'new')
x = open("report_mod.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)

x.close()
```

Where I'm stuck now is, how do I replace the double quotes ("") with single quotes (") for all the entries of the field column `Payee`?

In the above example, the 3 entries for the `Payee` is `""Carfax"`, `""Carfax"`, and `""USA Petroleum"`. I would like to replace the double quotes at the beginning with single quotes, i.e. `"Carfax"`, `"Carfax"`, and `"USA Petroleum"`

The new CSV file should look like so:

```
"Name";"Current balance";"Account";"Transfers";"Description";"Payee";"Category";"Date";"Memo";"Amount";"Currency";"Check #";"Tags"
"Capital One Quicksilver";"-119.99";"USD";"";"";"";"";";"";"";";"";""
"";"";"Capital One Quicksilver";"";"DMV";"Carfax";"";"08/19/2004";"";"-24.99";"USD";"";""
"";"";"Capital One Quicksilver";"";"DMV";"Carfax";"";"08/19/2004";"";"-24.99";"USD";"";""
"";"";"Capital One Quicksilver";"";"Gas";"USA Petroleum";"";"09/13/2004";"";"-20.43";"USD";"";""
```

Sample data file: [report.csv](https://file.io/9Pc3wocjiXU2)

Comment: Please [edit] to replace the off-site link with a small excerpt within the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex maybe

```py
import re
text = re.sub('^""$', '"' ,text)
```

so full code must be like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import re

# reading CSV file
data = pd.read_csv("report.csv",delimiter=';')

for val in data['Payee']:
    val = str (val)
    newVal = re.sub(r'"', '' ,val)
    newVal = '"'+newVal+'"'
    print(newVal)
```

the output is this on my terminal:

```bash
"nan"
"Carfax"
"Carfax"
"USA Petroleum"
```

Edit: Add full code to create the file

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import re

# reading CSV file
data = pd.read_csv("report.csv",delimiter=';')
names           = data['Name'].tolist();
balances        = data['Current balance'].tolist();
accounts        = data['Account'].tolist();
transfers       = data['Transfers'].tolist();
descriptions    = data['Description'].tolist();
categories      = data['Category'].tolist();
dates           = data['Date'].tolist();
memos           = data['Memo'].tolist();
amount          = data['Amount'].tolist();
currency        = data['Currency'].tolist();
check           = data['Check #'].tolist();
tags            = data['Tags'].tolist();

counter = 0
f = open("report_modified.csv", "w+")
f.write('"Name";"Current balance";"Account";"Transfers";"Description";"Payee";"Category";"Date";"Memo";"Amount";"Currency";"Check #";"Tags"\n');
for val in data['Payee']:
    val = str (val)
    newVal = re.sub(r'"', '' ,val)
    newVal = '"'+newVal+'"'
    print(newVal)
    f.write(str(names[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(balances[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(accounts[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(transfers[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(descriptions[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(newVal)+';')
    f.write(str(categories[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(dates[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(memos[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(amount[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(currency[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(check[counter])+';')
    f.write(str(tags[counter])+'\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: I see no changes to the entries using your provided solution.

Comment: okey i edit the code you can try with it

Comment: thanks but how do I modify the original file with the changes and write it to an output file? Apologies, I'm still learning Python.

Comment: you're welcome. I created a code block and edited the solution but dude u must try to use google before asking more. Cause I've never ever used numpy scipy csv or bla bla till now. I just created your solution from google and stackoverflow. :) I don't even know python I tried to add ';' end of each line lol

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get your solution to achieve what I want. The code just writes the field column names to another file, but no data entries. Apologies, I should have included the sample data file, please see OP.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what's wrong with solution? I read your question 3-4 more times but still think code gives what u want ??